# JNI Env in different threads and exceptions

Tags: android, multithreading, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Say that I have two native threads, A and B. In thread A I use JNI methods to get a Java object by invoking a java method (constructor, static method, etc) and get a global reference to it.

```
java_vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env,NULL);
j_ref_inputStream = env->CallObjectMethod(g_j_ref_btSocket,j_mid_getInputStream);
g_j_ref_inputStream = env->NewGlobalRef(j_ref_inputStream);
```

Now I pass my global reference to Thread B where I call a method on it:

```
java_vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env2,NULL);
jint b = env2->CallIntMethod(g_j_ref_inputStream,j_mid_read);
```

Calling read() on an InputStream will block Thread B (right?). To forcefully unblock Thread B I can try generating an IOException. So in Thread A I do:

```
env->callVoidMethod(g_j_ref_btSocket,j_mid_close);
```

But where do I catch this exception? I'm not too clear on JNI and native threads. Do I call the following in Thread A:

```
j_exception = env->ExceptionOccurred();
if(j_exception) // handle exception
```

Or in Thread B:

```
j_exception = env2->ExceptionOccurred();
if(j_exception) // handle exception
```

Or does it not matter? (please elaborate on why in either case)

Comment: Think of pending exceptions as objects held in thread-local storage.  They're set by the VM and can be queried from JNI.  If thread B does something in Java that causes an exception, and it gets thrown all the way back out to native code, then it's up to you to check for and handle the exception from JNI (or return to Java code where the throw "resumes").  In no event does an exception that happens in thread B affect the thread-local pending-exception object in thread A.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the JNI aspect of it. Just consider what you're trying to *do.* think of it in pure Java if it helps. You are trying to unblock thread B by closing a stream it is blocked reading. So B will get an exception.

In reality *both* threads should call 'ExceptionOccurred()' after *every* JNI call, not just the ones you're 'expecting' exceptions on. But thread B will get this exception.

Comment: I understood the first part of your answer but I didn't get why both threads should check for exceptions after every JNI call. Could you please elaborate?